# Check if an argument passed to a bash script is a file of a certain extension

Tags: bash, command-line

I would like to check if

- the number of command line arguments passed to a bash script equals to one
- the argument points to an existing file
- the argument ends with `.epub` (in other words, the file has `.epub` extension)

I have already dealt with the first and second requirement but I cannot deal with the last. My attemp is as follows:

```
if [ $# -eq 1 ] && [ -f $1 ] && [ ${"$1": -5} == ".epub" ]; then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
${"$1": -5}
```

With:

```
${1: -5}
```

Also, just in case the file name has spaces in it, apply double-quotes:

```
[ $# -eq 1 ] && [ -f "$1" ] && [ "${1: -5}" == ".epub" ]
```

#### Aside: Compatibility

Lastly, neither `==` not `${1: -5}` are POSIX.  If you want POSIX compatibility, use:

```
 [ $# -eq 1 ] && [ -f "$1" ] && [ "${1%.epub}" != "$1" ]
```

This will work not just with bash but with many other shells as well.

Comment: here there is another way to do the same thing and  mantain compatibility : 

`[ ".${1#*.}" == ".epub" ]` 

feel free to add it to your answer if you like it .

Comment: @D'ArcyNader I would have to be `##*.`, though, and the leading period isn't really required.

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes you are right about ##*. thanks. i think you still need the leading period or it 'll be not equal to ".epub"  that is what he asked.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader `[ ."$x" = .blah ]` is exactly the same as `[ "$x" = blah ]`.

Comment: i have no doubt .